# How can I tell which device purchased specific apps?

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore, hardware-recommendation

I have had a problem with children downloading apps. I would like to be able to see which apple device has purchased which app. How do I do that?

Comment: Are they all on the same Apple ID?

Answer (score 2):

Sync your iPhone to iTunes, Select the App you want to know from which account it has been purchased, right click, go to Get info, under the File tab you will find something like below image where you can see who purchased the app. I have removed my Apple ID but the different names is for different accounts.